# Transforming compoundcurve to JSON using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, json

How i can transform QGIS geometry form `compoundcurve` to `json`?

I tried `geometry.asJson()`, and it works fine for `linestring`. But when I use that method on `compoundcurve`, it returns me a lot of points (near 180) from arc (`circularstring`).

I want to get json with points of arc, like it in WKT:

`CircularString (1 1, 2 2, 3 1)` CircularString (start, mid, end).

At the end I want to get smth like JSON:

`{'type':'PolyLine', 'items':['line':[p1, p2, p3], 'arc':[start, mid, end], ...]}`

I tried transform geometry to WKT and parse it to my format, but thats really bad idia. I also tried split geometry to parts by `geometry().parts()` but it returns `<QgsCompoundCurve: CompoundCurve EMPTY>`.

Comment: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.asJson does GeoJSON and GeoJSON does no non-linear curve geometries.

Comment: Why parsing WKT was a bad idea?

Comment: To get three points as `[start, mid, end]`, you can proceed with `cString.startPoint(), cString.childPoint(1), ctring.endPoint()`

Comment: @Taras `[point for point in cString.vertices()]` would be better in my opinion and would also work for the linestrings that can be contained within compound curves geometries

Answer (score 1):

Compound curves are not supported by the GeoJSON format:

> GeoJSON (JSON) supports the following geometry types: Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, and GeometryCollection. ([source](https://stevage.github.io/geojson-spec/#section-1))

Which means that `asJson()` approximates the curve to create a compliant geometry type.

Comment: I know it. So i don't need GeoJSON. I want to transfer QgsCurve to 3 points (start, middle, end), and insert that points to json

Comment: Then your question has nothing to do with actually creating geojson/json geometries or json itself. your question should be about extracting the 3 points that make up a circular string so you can build your own custom 
 "json" geometry